# Cloudbees AWS Elastic Beanstalk deployment - application not found error

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cloudbees

I am trying to deploy application from Jenkins build from Dev@cloud to AWS
using the instructions given at
https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/ElasticBeanstalk

However, I am stuck because "cloudbees-deployer:elastic-beanstalk" is not
able to locate my application at AWS.

Here is the Console output from Jenkins Build

```
    [cloudbees-deployer:elastic-beanstalk] Checking if S3 bucket
    'photoid-reports-aws' exists...

    [cloudbees-deployer:elastic-beanstalk] Checking if S3 bucket
    'photoid-reports-aws' location...
    [cloudbees-deployer:elastic-beanstalk] S3 bucket 'photoid-reports-aws'
    location matches: us-east-1
    [cloudbees-deployer:elastic-beanstalk] Uploading application to S3
    bucket 'photoid-reports-aws/jenkins-photoid-reports-aws-9'...

    [cloudbees-deployer:elastic-beanstalk] Application uploaded to S3
    bucket 'photoid-reports-aws' with key
    'jenkins-photoid-reports-aws-9/deploytest', version id 'null' and eTag
    '427d78c1e5bfbaa7a1d10f46280236cc-8'
    [cloudbees-deployer:elastic-beanstalk] Checking if application version
    'prod-build' exists...
    [cloudbees-deployer:elastic-beanstalk] Creating application version
    'prod-build'...

    com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.exceptions.DeployException: No
    Application named 'deploytest' found. (Service: AWSElasticBeanstalk;
    Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID:
    0cc70036-470e-11e4-90e5-1717b7862a74)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.engines.Engine.process(Engine.java:185)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.engines.Engine.perform(Engine.java:119)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.DeployBuilder.perform(DeployBuilder.java:104)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:825)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:606)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1684)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:232)
    Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: No Application named
    'deploytest' found. (Service: AWSElasticBeanstalk; Status Code: 400;
    Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID:
    0cc70036-470e-11e4-90e5-1717b7862a74)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:820)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:439)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:245)
    at com.amazonaws.services.elasticbeanstalk.AWSElasticBeanstalkClient.invoke(AWSElasticBeanstalkClient.java:1679)
    at com.amazonaws.services.elasticbeanstalk.AWSElasticBeanstalkClient.createApplicationVersion(AWSElasticBeanstalkClient.java:540)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.impl.amazon.EngineImpl$DeployFileCallable.invoke(EngineImpl.java:355)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.impl.amazon.EngineImpl$DeployFileCallable.invoke(EngineImpl.java:224)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.engines.Engine$FingerprintingWrapper.invoke(Engine.java:271)
    at com.cloudbees.plugins.deployer.engines.Engine$FingerprintingWrapper.invoke(Engine.java:259)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2462)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:328)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    Build step 'Deploy applications' marked build as failure
    Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting. It looks like Cloudbees is assuming that you already have an application named "deploytest". The log looks like it is only trying to create a new application version as you can see after the S3 upload succeeded. It checks to make sure the app-version doesn't exist and then tries to create it.

What happens if you go through the [Elastic Beanstalk Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/home) to setup a new application with the name 'deploytest'? Just select the desired Environment Tier, Platform, and then Environment Type and try running that again. When it asks for application version, you can just use the sample app which should be selected by default.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I first created "deploytest" application through Beanstalk Console first and then ran the above in Cloudbees.

Comment: Are you using the same region in both cases?

Comment: I was using different regions. Thanks Josh.

Comment: Great, I'm glad we were able to figure it out.